# How do you make a box fadeout in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadeout

So I am trying to make a box fadeout in Jquery. I'm using an internal stylesheet. i've looked over the code again and again and don't know what is wrong with it. maybe the CDN I used is broke or not the right verison, but im sure you guys could tell me what I have done wrong. here is the code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#box {
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid blue;
background-color: black;
top: 100px;
left: 300px;
padding: 10px;
height: 60px;
width: 80px;
color: white;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"    src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="box">Box</div>
<script type="text/javascript"
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#box").hover(function(){
$(this).fadeOut('slow');
});
});

</body>




</html>
```

Comment: You didn't close your `<script>` tag.

Comment: <script>your code here</script>

Comment: You have to close your `</script>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to close your starting tag with `>` and have to have an ending tag `</script>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#box").hover(function () {
      $(this).fadeOut('slow');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Now when you `hover` over the box, it will `fadeOut`.

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#box").hover(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
#box {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: black;
  top: 100px;
  left: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 80px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">Box</div>
```

**Output: http://output.jsbin.com/cegidelulu**

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yeah, I've told them that a few times. It seems we've all fallen onto deaf ears. As per one of their latest questions. But, I'll upvote for your troubles ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ha ha... Thanks. Let's move on. I understand how it feels. Hope you too! `:P`

Comment: @PraveenKumar *"Moving on"* ;-) I hope all is well with you my friend.